# R Programming Language: Identificando columnas numéricas con 12 valores distintos o menos como categóricas

Tags: r

Cuando uno analiza datos, me parece buena idea identificar a variables numéricas que tienen pocos valores distintos como categóricas. El ejemplo perfecto es cuando solamente existen 0 y 1, que se podrían interpretar como apagado y encendido. Otro caso es cuando solamente tenemos 1, 5, y 10 ó 1, 2 y 3 que se podrían interpretar como "bajo", "medio", y "alto."

Para usar R, he elegido el dataset "mtcars."

El código está funcionando.

Tiene 2 pasos.

1. Encontrar las columnas numéricas que tienen 12 valores distintos o menos. Por supuesto, en lugar de 12 podr1an ser 6, 3, etc.
2. Convertir SOLAMENTE ESAS columnas numéricas a variables categóricas.

***Cómo podría mejorarse el código?***

```
library(tidyverse)

data(mtcars)
 
fun <- function(x) { x <= 12 }
 
columns_with_12_or_less_elements <- mtcars %>% select(where(is.numeric)) %>% lapply(n_distinct) %>% as.data.frame %>% select(where(fun)) %>% colnames
 
columns_with_12_or_less_elements
 
#original data.frame

str(mtcars)
 
#new data.frame

mtcars[,columns_with_12_or_less_elements] <- mtcars[,columns_with_12_or_less_elements] %>% lapply(as.factor) 

str(mtcars)  
View(mtcars)
```

[image: Dataframe antes y después]

---

En otro foro, alguien publicó otra respuesta. La pongo aquí, como se dice en matemáticas, "for completeness."

```
fun2<-function(x){n_distinct(x)<=12}

# es posible que se pueda con un solo select, pero no probé

mtcars %>% select(is.numeric) %>% select_if(fun2) %>% colnames() -> columns_with_12_or_less_elements

mtcars %>% mutate(across(c(columns_with_12_or_less_elements),factor)) %>% str()
```

Comment: Gracias! La dejaré en una.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitarías cargar todo el `tidyverse` sino solo `dplyr`.

Puede hacerse todo en una línea, pero crear una función hace que todo quede más claro.

```r
library(dplyr)

n_uniques <- function(x) x %>% unique() %>% length()
```

Se aprovecha la función `across()` añadida en dplyr 1.0, de este modo no hace falta usar `lapply()` ni crear tablas intermedias. El número de valores únicos solo hace falta indicarlo dentro de `mutate()`.

```r
mtcars %>% 
    mutate(across(.cols = where(~is.numeric(.x) && n_uniques(.x) <= 12), .fns = as.factor)) %>% 
    str()
#> 'data.frame':    32 obs. of  11 variables:
#>  $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#>  $ cyl : Factor w/ 3 levels "4","6","8": 2 2 1 2 3 2 3 1 1 2 ...
#>  $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
#>  $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
#>  $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
#>  $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
#>  $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
#>  $ vs  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 ...
#>  $ am  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ gear: Factor w/ 3 levels "3","4","5": 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
#>  $ carb: Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Fantástica respuesta! Gracias!